# Why is Grid Child with fixed width and max-width: 90% overflowing grid track

Tags: html, css, css-grid

## Question:

My question is very simple, I need to know why the `.header` element is overflowing its grid track when reaching the 1500px viewport width.

**Code:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #6e28d9;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-area: header;
  width: 1500px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-start">header start</div>
        <div class="header-end">header end</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

## What I wanted:

The idea is having the `.header` element have a width of 1500px. When there is not enough room, `.header` should take 90% of its grid track.

## What I tried:

I managed to get it done by setting `width: min(1500px, 90%)` and removing `max-width`  in the `.header` element, but don't really know what is happening. My guess is that grid track is calculating its width based on the width if the content. At this point I'm not really sure what `1fr` really means.

## Thoughts:

Everybody says that Grid is great but trouble always finds me when I leave the warmth of my Flexbox.

Comment: I just want to say that I think you should sell either t-shirts or mugs that says "trouble always finds me when I leave the warmth of my Flexbox"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, You are misunderstanding about Max-width, width and % in CSS.
In CSS, the element's width:10% means 10% of parent div's width. And pixel unit is static value in CSS.
Also the parent's min width is same with child div's width.
In your project, You set header's width as 1500px, so the parent element's minimal width is 1500px. As the result, the 90% of header is at least 1350px.
Please check the width of header's width using inspect in chrome, then you will notice that the minimal width of header is 1350px even you resize the width of the chrome viewport under 1500px.
That's because you set the width of header as 1500px, which means the min-width of parent div is 1500px.
To fix your code, please exchange two values of width and max-width. Then everything works good.
PS: you will see that when you resize the viewport under 1500px, then the letters are getting smaller than it's normal size. that's because the size of pixel is getting smaller relatively.

Comment: I guess that happens when you are a below average dev and you meet a pro dev. Jokes aside, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `90vw` instead of `90%` seems to work for this

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #6e28d9;
  color: white;
}

.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-area: header;
  width: 1500px;
  max-width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;

  border: 1px solid red; /*Added just to visualize the exact width*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-start">header start</div>
    <div class="header-end">header end</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already managed to do it but I want to know what is happening with the calculations of the grid. Basically what is causing the overflow.

Comment: You would have been better sorting out the header div first before setting it to display: flex for the children, because that shrink wraps the poor header. Setting a fixed width like 1500px is always asking for trouble, as that won't work well on lots of screens.

Comment: @ralph.m are you saying that I should have like a `.header-container` as the grid child and `.header-content` element as the flex container?. Even then, the example is not really that important, I'm trying to wrap my head around what is happening with the grid calculations.

Comment: Either way, I'd say just get the grid right first, then add in the flex elements, so that the two don't get confused.